# Flutter FutureBuilder & ListTile creation

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have written the code below. What it does is, using REST API it connects to the server, and placed order. In return I get the following JSON response:

```
{"status": "DONE", "response": {"message": "Your order saved.", "uuid": "fc1d6f52-9aef-11e3-84ae-0015af9e1aa1"}}
```

Every time I press "Raised Button", it connects to the server and creates a new order and provides me a new order UUID every time, and it shows in Text Widget. What I want to achieve is to call FutureBuilder or ListViewBuilder, so that every time I press "Raised Button", the builder will be triggered and ListTile (or Container) will appear containing new order UUID.

For example, if I press "Raised Button" 4 times, I want my UI to show 4 ListTile(or Container) each having unique order UUID. I tried looking for solutions and did not get lucky. I am new to Flutter, I just started learning it.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'model/orderTaxi_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
Future<OrderTaxi> _createOrder(String phone) async {
  final http.Response response = await http.post(
    'http://XXXXXXXXXXXXX/api/order',
    headers: <String, String>{
    },
    body: <String, String>{
      'api_key': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      'phone': phone,
      'street': 'Testttt',
      'moderation_required': 'yes',
    },
  );
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final Map responseString = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(responseString);
    return OrderTaxi.fromJson(responseString);
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to create order');
  }
}


class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  OrderTaxi _futureOrder;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Post Request'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          
          TextField(
            controller: _controller,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Place Order'),
            onPressed: () async {
              final String phone = _controller.text;
              OrderTaxi response = await _createOrder(phone);
              setState(() {
                _futureOrder = response;
              });
            },
          ),
          _futureOrder == null? Container(): Text('${_futureOrder.uuid}'),
        ],
      )
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Try to use StreamBuilder. The stream returns a list. When API returns an ID, add the ID to the list.

Comment: Is there any resource related to this problem which would assist me? You have?